# What is the method keyword used for in C#?

Tags: c#, keyword

This might be a stupid question, or oversight on my part, but..
If you type 'method' inside an attribute definition, as below:

```
[method: ]
public class MyClass
```

Visual Studio highlights the keyword. It doesn't seem to highlight it outside of an attribute as far as I can tell, and hitting F1 in VS boots you to a 404.

I've never seen this actually used, and I can't find any information on it.

Anyone know what it does?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Disambiguating Attribute Targets (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3787ac0%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Basically, it's to disambiguate between attribute applied to a method and attribute applied to the return value.

Comment: Perfect. This makes sense now. Odd that it doesn't appear in the keyword documentation and highlights as a keyword, and 404's.

Answer (score 1):

This determines that the attribute that follows the `method` keyword applies to the specific method. You can also declare attributes that apply not only for a single method or field, but even for a entire .dll or assembly. You can type also `module` or `assembly`.